# login from username or email id in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to have a login form that can login with email or username. 
I have studied about how it can be done via `Auth::attempt();` but want to know exact code. I am new to Laravel.

I want two text fields: one for email or username and another for password

So when user will clicks on login button it should check combination of email/username and password

I have tried `Auth::attempt`:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password])) {

    echo "success with username!";

} 
elseif (Auth::attempt(['email'=> $request->username, 'password' => $request->password])) {

    echo "success with email!"; 

} 
else {

    echo "fail!";

}
```

Comment: And what is the problem? Describe what happens.

Comment: its redirecting to login page

Comment: its not giving any messages

Comment: Edit the question with your clarifications so that it becomes clear.

Comment: See [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/login-with-email-or-mobile-or-username-in-laravel-53).

Comment: is there any option with out using attemtp function

Comment: `Auth::login($user)`.